# Distributing an executable that dynamically loads DLLs Fails when shared via the web, works on physical thumb drives

Tags: .net, windows, dll

**One Solution Found**
The operating system marks files downloaded from the internet 'blocked' and right clicking and unblocking via the properties dialog will work. Is there any *quicker* ways that anyone knows of to do this (I have many DLLs and each has to be unblocked manually!).

### Interestingly: Only the DLL's loaded from outside the running directory were 'blocked'.

I wrote an application which relies on it's directory structure to function, the structure looking something like this:

```
MyApp > App     > bin       > myapp.exe

        Plugins > myapp1.dll
                  myapp2.dll
```

This works perfectly fine on my machine, and I've tried the following methods of distribution to my peers:

1. Copying the folder to a thumb drive and dropping it on their machine. (Works in many different directories) **WORKS**
2. Zipping the folder and repeating the above **WORKS**
3. Uploading the zip to bitbucket and downloading it on other computers **FAILS** the program simply crashes, saying it cannot load the dlls in ../../Plugins.
4. Uploading the uncompressed files to both bitbucket and a webserver at my office has the same issue as 3.

Does anyone know of any Windows security traits that don't allow programs downloaded from the internet to dynamically load DLLs that aren't in the running directory?

Comment: As usual with DLL problems, what does Dependency Walker say?

Comment: @MSalters Not a dependency issue, as I mentioned it works when the same thing is packaged and transfered on a disk. It is a security issue. The only solution I have now is to right click each and every DLL and say 'unblock'

Answer (score 0):

The NTFS Alternate stream named "Zone.Identifier" holds a line `ZoneId=3` which tells Windows that the DLL was downloaded, and therefore blocked. Since the DLL is not visibly associated with the executable, unblocking the executable doesn't affect the DLL.